# No externally managed transaction is currently active for this thread (only persistent queries !!)

Tags: jpa, persistence, jta, spring-transactions, transactionmanager

Hello I have been working on a web application with Spring 4 and EclipseLink on GlassFish server . 
I use a wampserver for mySQL server and a connexion pool on GlassFish.

Here is my persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="NetworkAdministrationBD_pu" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>networkadminDB2</jta-data-source>
        <class>tn.insat.entities.Administrateur</class>
        <class>tn.insat.entities.Responsable</class>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

My DAO bean "AdministrateurDAOImpl" is annotated with @Repository("administrateurDao")

My spring configuration xml file is :

```
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="tn.insat.dao" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="tn.insat.web"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="tn.insat.service"/>
    <tx:annotation-driven/>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="NetworkAdministrationBD_pu"/>
    </bean>

   ...
```

The EntityManager is properly injected in the administrateurDao bean :

```
 private EntityManager em;

    @PersistenceContext
    public void setEm(EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;
    }
```

The "administrateurDao" object works fine when non persistent queries are executed in JPQL or directly through EntityManager method ( em.find() )

However , when persistent queries are executed (such as em.remove() ) I get the above exception .

The delete method form "administrateurDao" looks like this :

```
try{ 
Query query = em.createQuery("DELETE FROM Administrateur a WHERE a.id = :id");
            query.setParameter("id", id);
            query.executeUpdate();
}
catch (Exception e){
throw new DAOException() ;
}
```

After some debugging and tests I have discovered that the error is thrown at the

```
query.executeUpdate();
```

command .

I don't know if it is relevant but also the "administrateurDao" repository bean is used by a GWT RPC service .

I have been through all internet questions and documentations and none of them propose a solution without having to change either the transaction_type from JTA to RESOURCE_LOCAL or switching the hole persistence layer .

Also adding @Transactional annotation provokes another exception :

```
Exception Description: Cannot use an EntityTransaction while using JTA.
```

I have been stuck for too long , any ideas ?